# LDAP-Search in 2 organizational units

Tags: c#, ldap

Due to some changes on AD-level I have to change a lookup in AD in my application. The search must now be executed in 2 different OU instead of 1.

At this moment I run a second search if the first one returns nothing.

Is it possible to combine the 2 paths into 1 so have to search only once?

Thx.

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry())
{
    de.Path = "LDAP://OU=ou1,OU=Users,OU=BE,DC=dc,DC=sys";
    de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    var deSearch = new DirectorySearcher
    {
        SearchRoot = de,
        Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sAMAccountName=" + userId + "))"
    };

    var result = deSearch.FindOne();

    if (result == null)
    {
        //User not found in ou1
        de.Path = "LDAP://OU=ou2,OU=Users,OU=BE,DC=dc,DC=sys";
        de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        deSearch = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            SearchRoot = de,
            Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sAMAccountName=" + userId + "))"
        };

        result = deSearch.FindOne();

        if (result==null) return null;
    }

    using (var deUser = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot search in 2 OU's at once - you'll have to do your two searches separately, and combine the results.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I'll keep it the way it is. If you post this as an answer, the Q can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the base object to `OU=Users,OU=BE,DC=dc,DC=sys`, use the same filter, use a scope of `sub` or `one` (depending on where the data is located under the organizational units). For more information about searching a directory, see "[LDAP: Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)" and "[LDAP: Programming Practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)".

Comment: I've already put it in production like it is in my Q, but I will definitely take a look at this. Thanks.

Comment: Just made a quick test. Changing the path as you mentioned and kept the filter like it was. It gave me the same result as before, so it works. But is there a way to test if the result is part of one of the OU's mentioned above? Best property I can find is 'distinguishedName -- CN=John Doe,OU=ou1,OU=Users,OU=BE,DC=ds,DC=sys'.