# Searching Users in Multiple OUS in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I search users in active Directory in Multiple Organizational Units using Single LDAP search Filter?

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820419/ldap-search-in-2-organizational-units

Answer (score 0):

In order to search multiple OUs using a single LDAP filter, you should target the base of your search at a top-level OU that contains all the OUs you are interested in searching, and perform an Tree Scope search. I believe this should do it for you.

If you are looking to multiple individual OUs in a single LDAP search, I don't believe that is possible in a single LDAP search. You could do multiple LDAP searches, one to each OU, and then collate the results, but I don't think you can specify multiple target DNs in a single LDAP search.